# About the MousewheelListener forNode

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

I have a problem I cannot solve; adding a MousewheelListener to a `Node`.

I'm trying to make a `Pane` where the size changes when you scroll with the mouse, but I can't find anything called "MouseWheelListener" in the API.

How do I make a listener that makes a `Pane` react to scrolling?

Comment: Can you add on your question what you tried so far?! A code snipped, or maybe this guide could help you [SSCC](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event for scrolling the mouse wheel in JavaFX is called [`ScrollEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html).

You can either add an `EventHandler` to the node.

```
node.addEventHandler(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, (ScrollEvent event) -> {
    // Code for resizing the pane
});
```

#### Alternatively (Using FXML)

Inside of the fxml file where you add `onScroll` to your Pane:

```
<Pane fx:id="pane" onScroll="#nameOfMethodToBeOverridden">
  ...
</Pane>
```

*(If you are using `SceneBuilder`, this can be done in `Code` Section)*

In the **Controller**, you can handle the `onScroll` by using:

```
@FXML
private Pane pane;

@FXML
private void nameOfMethodToBeOverridden(){
     // Code for resizing the pane
}
```

Comment: This is my first time to post questions here，Thank you very much for your help, is very useful to me

Answer (score 0):

To listen for scroll events on a node, you use

```
node.addEventHandler(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, (ScrollEvent event) -> {
   // code to execute on scroll...
});
```

Comment: This is my first time to post questions here，Thank you very much for your help, is very useful to me